# "ifconfig" command gives different output than earlier in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and eth0 is also missing from the output. How do I reset it?

Tags: networking, command-line, 16.04, ethernet, ifconfig

I am not getting eth0 when I type "ifconfig" in terminal. Even the output I get is different from the output which I used to get earlier. Below is the output which I am getting right now :-

```
gkv@GKVInnovations:~$ ifconfig
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 8c:dc:d4:d2:d5:60  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:538 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:538 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:41686 (41.6 KB)  TX bytes:41686 (41.6 KB)

wlo1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:10:b3:3d:02:30  
      inet addr:192.168.0.5  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::fe8a:380d:89ea:7dce/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2282 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1990096 (1.9 MB)  TX bytes:384929 (384.9 KB)

gkv@GKVInnovations:~$
```

Earlier I used to get **eth0** instead of **enp1s0** and I think **wlan0** or **wlo**(I don't know it completely) instead of **wlo1**. I think RX and TX values are also different. I don't know more about what I used to get. But I believe there is some problem in network adapter or driver. Please help me to get default settings back and the default output which I used to get when I typed "ifconfig" in the terminal. Please help me resolve this issue !

One more thing is that I experienced this issue after using Kali Linux live mode. Earlier I was not getting that problem even in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Yes I read that. But I was checking kali linux through live install. I was using its applications like reaver and airmon -ng. I switched wireless connection to spy mode from managed mode. After that, when I ran my Ubuntu 16.04, I got this problem.

Comment: I think the question shown by you is similar but not duplicate to mine. As it had encountered that problem in a completely different way.

Comment: I am unable to get why this happened only after using live mode of Kali Linux !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was implemented to avoid a problem on computers with more than one NIC. It was never guaranteed you would get eth0 and eth1 named consistently among NICs. New way is to use hardware position of the card. It is confusing when you see it first time, but unless you have very strong reason, just don't fight it, it is not a bug, it is how it is going to be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But I have edited my question a bit right now and included some more details. Please review it once again and provide your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Could it be automatic update took place in the meantime ? To me this happened on Raspberry, it was eth0 and after reboot it was renamed. Automatic update changed it.

Comment: Maybe you are right !